# How to contain my mouse pointer within a canvas/div?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, mouse-cursor, pointerlock

I am currently trying to make a small html5 canvas game.
I want my mouse pointer to stay within a div element or canvas boundary.

Point me in the right direction please.

Comment: may be it will help u: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581513/jquery-follow-mouse-curser-within-in-a-div-centered-on-page

Answer (score 2):

You can use the new [Pointer Lock API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Pointer_Lock). It is now supported by Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Opera, and Safari.

Excerpt from the article linked above (my emphasis):

> The Pointer Lock API (formerly called Mouse Lock API) provides input methods based on the movement of the mouse over time (i.e., deltas), not just the absolute position of the mouse cursor in the viewport. It gives you access to raw mouse movement, **locks the target of mouse events to a single element**, eliminates limits on how far mouse movement can go in a single direction, and removes the cursor from view. It is ideal for first person 3D games, for example.
>
> More than that, the API is useful for any applications that require significant mouse input to control movements, rotate objects, and change entries, for example allowing users to control the viewing angle by moving the mouse around without any button clicking. The buttons are then freed up for other actions. Other examples include apps for viewing maps or satellite imagery.
>
> Pointer lock lets you access mouse events even when the cursor goes past the boundary of the browser or screen. For example, your users can continue to rotate or manipulate a 3D model by moving the mouse without end. Without Pointer lock, the rotation or manipulation stops the moment the pointer reaches the edge of the browser or screen. Game players can now click buttons and swipe the mouse cursor back and forth without worrying about leaving the game play area and accidentally clicking another application that would take mouse focus away from the game.

Also see the link for examples.

Comment: +1 Interesting find--mouse capture on steroids.  Chuckle: "We have control of your mouse. We will not release your mouse until you click the buy-now button..."

Comment: @markE could be an interesting scenario :) Luckily, the user will be prompted to accept the locking (as with f.ex. full-screen mode).