# Apply hover from the cursor position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need get hover effect in a `div` from the cursor position.

I have this `html` and `css`

```css
.f {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.s {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin: 75px 0px 0px 75px;
  transition: width 1s, height 1s, margin 1s;
}

.s:hover {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 50px 0px 0px 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="f">
  <div class="s"></div>
</div>
```

And I need something like this:

[image: Imagen 1]
[image: Imagen 2]

I'm open to js or jquery solutions.

### EDIT

I have a jquery solution:

```js
$("div.f").mousemove(function(e) {
  $('div.s').css({
    left: e.clientX - 28,
    top: e.clientY - 24
  });
});
```

```css
.f {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 100px;
  /* comment or remove the overflow if necessary */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.s {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="f">
  <div class="s"></div>
</div>
```

But i need the circle make the over animation like first snippet.

Original question [here](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/53560/aplicar-hover-desde-la-posici%C3%B3n-del-cursor)

Comment: Are you trying to position the black circle so that it "follows" the cursor?

Comment: Not exactly, i trying when im enter in div the hover effects apear in cursor position

Comment: You're likely going to need to do this with javascript, as the hover event in CSS can only apply static styling.

Comment: [Here is something similar](http://jsfiddle.net/amaan/ZnVsf/). This method is done with hitboxes and only css, adding many divs to detect where the cursor is. A better way is to use javascript, here's [one example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581513/jquery-follow-mouse-curser-within-in-a-div-centered-on-page)

Comment: If you are open for js solutions you should tag your question with js

Comment: Are you open to an jQuery/JavaScript solution ?

Comment: @Pugazh, yes im open to js or jquery solutions

Comment: @NenadVracar ,yes im open to js or jquery solutions

Comment: @pol ,yes im open to js or jquery solutions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change position of inner circle you can use `pageX` and `pageY` on mousemove. To change size of inner circle you can create one class that will `scale` div and toggle that class on hover over `.f`.

```js
var s = $('.s')
var f = $('.f')
var oTop = f.offset().top + (s.height() / 2);
var oLeft = f.offset().left + (s.width() / 2);

f.hover(function() {
  s.toggleClass('change')
})

f.mousemove(function(e) {
  var x = e.pageY - oTop
  var y = e.pageX - oLeft

  s.css({
    top: x + 'px',
    left: y + 'px'
  })
})
```

```css
.f {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
.s {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: transform 0.5s linear, opacity 0.3s linear;
}
.change {
  transform: scale(2);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="f">
  <div class="s"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just remove overflow: hidden.

Comment: When i do it, i don't get hover efect like the first snippet, only the circle can appear out of big circle

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by that.

Comment: Srry, i have very bad english. When i remove `overflow:hidden` i dont get expected effect. I need get effect like the hover in my question first snipper (the black circle make bigger).

Comment: Yep, this is ok. And you can do it this effect but show black circle only in the grey circle (like my second snippet).

Comment: Yes, exactly like this. Thank you, edit your answer and i accept it.

Comment: Oh, one more thing, you can do the black circle dont appear if you haven´t the cursor in the grey circle?(Srry :) )

Comment: Thank you,you are the best :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a jQuery solution.

```js
$("div.f").mousemove(function(e) {
  $('div.s').css({
    left: e.clientX - 28,
    top: e.clientY - 24
  });
});
```

```css
.f {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 100px;
  /* comment or remove the overflow if necessary */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.s {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="f">
  <div class="s"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.f').on('mousemove', function(e){
var par = $(this);
  if((e.pageX <= par.width() && e.pageX >= 0) && e.pageY <= par.height() && e.pageY >= 0){
    $('.s').css({
       position: 'relative',
       left:  e.pageX - (par.width() / 2),
       top:   e.pageY - (par.height() / 2)
    });
    } else {
    $('.s').css({
      position: 'initial'
    });
    }
});
```

```css
.f {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.s {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin: 75px 0px 0px 75px;
  transition: width 1s, height 1s, margin 1s;
}

.s:hover {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 50px 0px 0px 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="f">
  <div class="s"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function moveInner(e)
{
  var inner = document.getElementById('inner');
 
  inner.style.top = (e.clientY-100)+"px";
  inner.style.left= (e.clientX-100)+"px";
}
```

```css
.f {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.s {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin: 75px 0px 0px 75px;

  position: absolute;
}


Please put the inner div outside the parent div
And set the onmouseover for parent div to change inner div's position
```

```html
<div class="f" id="parent" onmousemove="moveInner(event)">
  
</div><div class="s" id="inner"></div>
```

Comment: Yes I can, please wait for a few minutes

Answer (score 0):

```js
var ol_x= null;
var ol_y= null;
function moveInner(me, e)
{
if(ol_x!=null)
{
var ctx = me.getContext("2d");
 ctx.arc(ol_x, ol_y, 42, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
 ctx.fillStyle='grey';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
}
ol_x = e.clientX+20;
ol_y = e.clientY+20;
  var ctx = me.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(ol_x, ol_y, 40, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
ctx.fillStyle ='black';
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();

}
```

```css
.f {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

Hi this is my solution for EDIT<BR>
I use 2D context to draw inner DIV inside parent DIV
```

```html
<canvas class="f" id="parent" onmousemove="moveInner(this, event)">
  
</canvas>
```