# JavaScript / CSS - How can I start an animation, creating new Divs from cursor position?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, onclick

I'd need to create Divs from the position where I click on the page that move from left to right. Is there a way to change constantly the position where I can start the animation? instead of having a fixed left and a fixed right? I was using keyframes with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PLease try this:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="startleft">
    <div class="box">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
}
.box {
  margin: 5px;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

JS

```
var container = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
container.onclick = function(e) {
  console.log("startleft");

  var offset = e.offsetX; 
  var startleft = document.getElementsByClassName("startleft")[0];
  startleft.setAttribute("style", "padding-left:"+ offset + "px");
};
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/YasirKamdar/pen/aqaMpj

This will set the offset to start, You can use animation as you want using the offset value received

Comment: Is it possible to have the same code using "normal" java script, instead of Jquerry? thank you!

Comment: Done, please check above

Answer (score 0):

html code

```
<div class="move-me move-me-1">steps(4, end)</div>
<br>
<div class="move-me move-me-2">steps(4, start)</div>
<br>
<div class="move-me move-me-3">no steps</div>
```

scss code :

```
.move-me {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
.move-me-1 {
  animation: move-in-steps 8s steps(4) infinite;
}
.move-me-2 {
  animation: move-in-steps 8s steps(4, start) infinite;
}
.move-me-3 {
  animation: move-in-steps 8s infinite;
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
}

@keyframes move-in-steps {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    background: blue;
  }
  100% {
    left: 100%;
    background: red;
  }
}
```

and this link help [This link try it](https://css-tricks.com/using-multi-step-animations-transitions/)

Thanks

Comment: I was looking for a way to start the animation from the cursor coordinates, this is a simple animation that starts from a selected x and y axis. Thanks!

Comment: This link try it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42644776/apply-hover-from-the-cursor-position