# Javascript/CSS: How to start animation from cursor position

Tags: javascript, css

I've already asked this question but it did not solve my problem ([JavaScript / CSS - How can I start an animation, creating new Divs from cursor position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48972654/javascript-css-how-can-i-start-an-animation-creating-new-divs-from-cursor-p)).

I've found a solution but it doesn't seem to work properly on Mozilla and Opera. Also, when I click multiple times, the div starts flashing, which is not what I want. I need to have more than one div at the same time, so to have multiple animations simultaneously. Here's an example from an existing game: http://www.cram.com/flashcards/games/stellar-speller/gre-hit-parade-group-1-320949 Please don't use jQuery, just normal Javascript. Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
   <head>
   <style>
     #table{
   height:300px;
   width:900px;
  background:red;

     }
 #ball {
     width: 25px;
     height: 25px;
     position: absolute;
       background-color: white;
     border-radius:50px;
    display:none;
    z-index:11;


   }
   </style>
   <script>  function animation(){ var elem = 
    document.getElementById("ball"); 
   document.getElementById("ball").style.display ='block';
    document.getElementById("ball").disabled = true;
  var x = event.clientX;
   var y = event.clientY;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 2);
   function frame() {
    if (x == 900) {
    clearInterval(id);

   } 
  else {
  x++;   
  elem.style.top = y + 'px';
  elem.style.left = x + 'px'; 
   }
   }
     }
   </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="table" onclick="animation()">
    <div id="ball"></div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: You should try to ask a self-contained question, rather asking people to read lots of background material before they can try to help you with your specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

few issues in your code. First you have to clone or create a new ball each time you click (be aware that [cloning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) an element won't copy attached events). Don't mix HTML and Javascript and use addEventListener, which let you have event as argument

```js
document.getElementById('table').addEventListener("click",animation);

function animation(event){
    var ball = document.getElementById("ball");
    //clone element or create another one (you should set a class in you css)
    var elem = ball.cloneNode(true);
  document.getElementById("table").appendChild(elem);

    elem.style.display ='block';
//    document.getElementById("ball").disabled = true;
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;
 
    var id = setInterval(frame, 2);
    
    function frame() {
        if (x == 900) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } 
        else
        {
            x++;
            elem.style.top = y + 'px';
            elem.style.left = x + 'px'; 
        }
    }
}
```

```css
#table{
  height:300px;
  width:900px;
  background:red;
}

#ball {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius:50px;
  display:none;
  z-index:11;
}
```

```html
<div id="table">
    <div id="ball"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried your code but there's a problem with the evenlistener, it's says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null", but I don't undestand why, it's working here on stock overflow

Comment: you have to put the script at the end of the page, after the DOM is loaded

Answer (score 0):

You're reusing the same `#ball` element for every animation, it can't be in two places at once. To create a new element each time, use `document.createElement`. Then you'll have to place that element somewhere with `appendChild`, and remove it with `removeChild` when the animation's finished.

And some smaller things:

If you will have more than one `ball` in the document, use a class instead of an ID - IDs are only supposed to be used once.

Your `<div>`s aren't closed with `</div>` in the HTML, which is probably Firefox's problem. Do people still use Opera?

You should use `requestAnimationFrame` here instead of `setInterval`.

And you should try to use `addEventListener` instead of `onclick`.

Good luck!